# Write numpy array to csv file with a specific number of columns

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape (444,445), and I need to dump it as a `csv` file. One can achieve this by:

```
np.savetxt('outfile.txt',array, delimiter=',',fmt="%s")
```

I use the `fmt="%s"` option, because at the end of each row (the 444 element of the array, is `NaN`).

What I would like to accomplish is to write a `csv` file that is 5 column wide, with 39,516 total lines (that is, 89 sections each of which consist of 5 columns and 444 lines), and finally the `NaN` written as an empty element on the end of the 444th line. In this way, one has the number of elements of the matrix that are equivalent: `89x5x444=444x445`, or 197,580 pieces of data.

For instance:

```
  1 xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,
  2 xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,
    ...
    ...
 89 xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,
 90 xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,
 91 xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,
    ...
    ...
178 xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,
```

I have added the line number to be more clear in my question. I do not want it in the actual output.

What would be an efficient and pythonic way of doing so?

For the moment, I am trying to adapt the answer to this question to my case:

[Write to list to rows with specific number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926584/write-to-list-to-rows-with-specific-number-of-columns).

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want 444 separate csv files...?

Comment: @RickTeachey well, in some way yes. Because 5 columns times 89 lines is 444. I tried reshaping my array to  (89,5,444) but np.savetxt does not give me back what I need.

Comment: if your array is of shape 444x445, there are 197,580 pieces of data. if i understand, what you want is a csv file that is 39,516 lines long (with 5 columns), correct? and the 89th line, 178th line, etc, will end in 'nan'. is that right?

Comment: @RickTeachey that is correct.

Comment: Actually the 89th line, 178th line, etc,  should not end with 'nan' but have one less element. I don't think this can be achieved with a single call to `numpy.savetxt()`. With masked arrays you can obtain something like `xxxx,xxxx,,` i.e. not a row with one less element, but a row with an empty element.

Comment: One thing you should do is provide an attempt at doing this yourself in the form of actual code. It doesn't have to be much, but it should be a solid "first try". You're much more likely to get good answers that way.

Comment: @StefanoM Upon reading it through again, I see that yes you're right.

Comment: @RickTeachey I think I succeeded in having a code that seems to work. Let me test it better, and I will put it here.

Comment: If it does work, make sure you post it as an answer to your own question. There is nothing wrong with that - in fact it is encouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I well understand what you are asking for

```py
# Reshape it

array_.reshpe(89,444,5)

# Change it's dtype to str so you can replace NaN by white spaces

array_.astype(str)

# Replace nan by white spaces

array_[array_ == 'nan'] = ''


# Finaly, save it SEE EDIT
```

**Edit**

I think that `np.savetxt` wouldn"t work with numpy arrays with more than 2 dimension, so, and referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685265/how-to-write-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-text-file) we can try this:

```py
# Write the array to disk
with file('test.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    # I'm writing a header here just for the sake of readability
    # Any line starting with "#" will be ignored by numpy.loadtxt
    outfile.write('# Array shape: {0}\n'.format(array_.shape))

    # Iterating through a ndimensional array produces slices along
    # the last axis. This is equivalent to array_[i,:,:] in this case
    for data_slice in array_:

        # The formatting string indicates that I'm writing out
        # the values in left-justified columns 7 characters in width
        # with 2 decimal places.  
        np.savetxt(outfile, data_slice, fmt='%-7.2f')

        # Writing out a break to indicate different slices...
        outfile.write('# New slice\n')
```

Comment: Sorry @muammar it's `array_[array_ == 'nan'] = ''`

Comment: There is also `reshape`. I like a lot your solution, but when you try to save the `.astype(str)` array without the `nan` ->  ` TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: @muammar, I realize that there is a problem with saving a numpy array with (a,b,c) as shape. take a look to the edit and tell me if it works or you want to customize it

Comment: To save in disk, the fmt has to be set to `fmt='%s'`, otherwise it fails. Thank you very much for your help. I will mark your solution as the correct answer.

Comment: it's my pleasure dude =)